# Easy SMTP/POP3 Server for multiple domains

Tags: linux, smtp, email-server, pop3

I've got a `postfix` & `dovecot` setup running on my Ubuntu 10.4 server. This works good but the configuration/management seems a bit overblown for my use case. Now I need to reinstall this Server and I'm looking for a solution that is easier to maintain.

Can you suggest a setup with the following features:

- Can recieve/send mail for multiple domains + subdomains
- Recieves mail for all valid email-addresses (catch-all) into one mail account
- Accepts all valid mail-addresses as sender
- IMAP would be a plus but isn't required

Basically I just want scripts to send E-Mail from the server with abritary senders and recieve E-Mail for all possible addresses/domains and then fetch them into my gmail-account.

Answer (score 1):

If you are too lazy to set this up, I suggest you take a look at [iRedmail](http://www.iredmail.org/).
*A ZERO COST, fully fledged, full-featured mail server solution. All components are free and open source softwares*.

It's super easy to install, you can have what you want running in less than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

I am using postfix / courier for this scenario.
The setup uses mysql/virtual everywhere possible, this way i only need to maintain a few tables in order to configure/manage the whole mail system.
It provides SMTP, IMAP(S), POP(S), atmail, spamfiltering through DNSBLs and SpamAssassin

This tutorial would be a good point to start: [HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual_postfix_mysql_quota_courier)

It seems daunting at first, but once you have it set up you would not want to miss it.
Just think about the flexibility you will have by maintaining everything in mysql, you can easily create your own little webinterface for managing users, domains, forwardings and so on.

Comment: Ill take a look at the Howto but tbh it sounds even more overblown than my current setup.

Comment: i am rather amazed that you think this is overblown and i would be surprised if there is a "roll your own" multi-domain, multi-user mailserver that does not need to be setup.